# Что нужно сделать, чтобы данные телеграмм бота на Heroku не удалялись?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, heroku, aiogram

Создал телеграмм бота на Python aiogram , который должен добавлять Id пользователя в таблицу SQLite3 при запуске бота, бот отлично работает локально, но при загрузке на Heroku, новые id пользователей, добавленные в таблицу - удаляются в течении 24 часов.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать, чтобы добавленные новые данные в таблицу не удалялись в течении суток на Heroku?

Comment: sqlite не асинхронный, зачем его юзать?

Comment: А какую можно использовать базу данных? Postgresql подойдёт?

Comment: [Тут написано](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted), что для персистентного хранилища на Heroku нужно использовать соответствующие аддоны, либо внешние сервисы типа aws s3 (для статики). Файлы, которые вы сохраняете внутри dyno не будут сохранены после перезапуска dyno.

Answer (score 0):

На файловую систему в Heroku полагаться [нельзя](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted), она может очищена в любой момент.

Для персистентного хранилища используйте соответствующие [дополнения](https://elements.heroku.com/addons), например, для реляционной базы данных есть дополнение [Heroku Postgres](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql).

Comment: Обязательно использовать Heroku Postgres? Могу ли я просто добавить в мой код таблицу Postgresql ?

Comment: Можете добавить, но где будете хранить? На файлы вы полагаться не можете, они будут очищаться. Ничего сохранить [не сможете](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) без дополнений (так, чтобы это не потерялось после следующей перезагрузки). Там есть [26 разных дополнения](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#data-stores) для хранения данных. Из них SQL базы это: MariaDB, PostgreSQL, ClearDB, MSSQL, JawsDB.

Comment: То есть, нужно использовать Heroku дополнение обязательно?